# Mapbox gl geojson layer disappears on higher zoom

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a geojson representing contour layers of interpolated weather data. 
Certain *contours* disappear at higher zoom levels as seen in following screengrab.
[image: Layer disappears on higher zoom]

When adding the multipolygon to Mapbox as a layer, using the following code:

```
map.addSource('mintempContour', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: geojson_source
        });

        map.addLayer({
            "id": 'mintemp',
            "type": "fill",
            "minzoom": 2,
            "maxzoom": 15,
            "source": "mintempContour",
            "layout": {
                'visibility': 'visible'
            },
            "paint": {
                "fill-color": { type: 'identity', property: 'fill' },
                "fill-opacity": 1

            }

            //"filter": ["==", "$type", "Polygon"]
        }, 'water');
```

I have tested the geojson file on sites like geojson.io and the contours remain visible at all zoom levels.

I want all contours to be present all the time, regardless of the zoom level. How can I fix this?

Quick and dirty JSFiddle replicating issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/stefmarais/ae9nzmrt/12/

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `maxZoom` when calling `addLayer`, which according to the docs does:

> The maximum zoom level for the layer. At zoom levels equal to or greater than the maxzoom, the layer will be hidden.
>   https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layer-maxzoom

I think you actually want to set `maxzoom` on the source, not the layer:

> Maximum zoom level at which to create vector tiles (higher means greater detail at high zoom levels).
>   https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-geojson-maxzoom

(or just none at all).

Comment: The layer is hidden while zoom is between 2 and 15, i.e. the bounds given in addLayer.

Not setting the min and max zoom does not solve the problem.